# HP 8300 CMT Upgrade - Fan runs for one second and then nothing happens

Tags: boot, graphics-card, power-supply, troubleshooting

I have a HP 8300 CMT with a i5 3570 where I initially had a 500 W PSU connected to the MoBo with the 24 pin -> 6 pin adapter. I am currently planning on adding a GTX 1060 that I also already have here.

I have finally found a configuration of the adapter where I get a reaction of the motherboard. The issue is, the fans only run for approx. 1 sec and then nothing happens. I have read that this might be due to a faulty PSU and so I have tried my old PSU from another pc which does not have this 8 pin PCI-E pins, so I left the GPU out (while still inserted to the motherboard). And it turns out that the fans run!

I figured it must be the PSU and now I have tried a EVGA 600W connected to the 24p adapter, the 4 pin MoBo and to the 8 pin PCI E GPU. And now I have the same thing! 1 sec of fans running and then nothing.

I am still not sure about the 24pin adapter 6 pin configuration, but why would the old PSU then run? Could the GPU be at fault? Or did I get two brand new PSU that simply don't work?

Edit: I have some more new details:
I have tried another pin configuration on the 6 pin connector and the PC started running (at least the fans were running) but it beeped 4 or 5 times. Unfortunately, I did not have a monitor connected, so I don't know if there was anything on the screen. Then I have tried to connect a monitor with literally nothing else changed, but the PC fans again only run for 1 sec and nothing happened. 
So I think I still don't know the correct configuration of the pins and due to the constant re-pinning of the connector, I don't think I have good contact on those pins anymore. I have now ordered a new adapter so I can start fresh.

If anyone has a 100% correct pin-configuration on the 6 pin connector, that would be perfect! I have already seen the resources on youtube, linustechtips.com and the hp forum, but the configuration differ everytime.

Edit 2: I have more news!
I have tried another pin configuration and it managed to start booting eventually. The setup:
- The new EVGA PSU
- GTX 1060 NOT connected
- Both RAM inserted
- CMOS button pressed for 10 seconds
It started the same with 1 second of the fans running. I then just kept the Power button pressed and eventually the pc booted up and these were the outputs on the display.
The first boot screen with the expected fan error
[First image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PrY7.png)

After pressing F1
[Second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMExT.png)

Since nothing is on the drive:
[Third image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upFvc.png)

The weird thing is, that the PC boots up every 15 times of pressing the power button. It is not consistent at all and I cannot replicate this everytime.

Do you have anymore advice? Thank you!

Comment: To clarify, when you say that the fan spin for 1 sec and then nothing, you mean that the computer does not turn on/start ? And then, you have the 24 pin and the 6 pin on the motherboard? Motherboard and pci-e connectors are wired different. If I am not wrong pci-e has all the negative on the same side, but the motherboard does not?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply.

Yes, the fan spin for 1 sec and then nothing happens - the pc turns off.

I have an adapter from 24 pin to 6 pin/4 pin as HP brings out proprietory PSUs. The 6 pin needs to be reconfigurated according to the model of the hp computer, and I found a way where I get at least the fan running for 1 sec, but I am 0% sure that this is the correct configuration.

What I meant by mentioning the PCI-E is, that the PSU is connected at those points. 24 pin, which connects to 6pin/4pin and other 4 pin close to the CPU and to the 8pin of the GPU.

Comment: If I understand it correctly your connection looks good. 1060 cards usually don't need that much current. One possibility is that is not correclty plugged in the pci connector on the motherboard. Check it twice!

Comment: if there is anything that I might have forgotten, i would be bery thankful if you could let me know

Comment: I have checked the GPU and it fits correctly on the motherboard - still no sign from the pc :(

Comment: If you can provide the beeping seguence "but it beeped 4 or 5 times"  we can try to sort out what kind of error it is